# Dashboard Mash-Up Using Angular Lazy-Load Modules?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, dashboard

I'd like to implement lazy-loaded modules in my Angular 5 app to speed up initial load time. But my landing page is a dashboard, a mashup of 'widgets' that span almost all those modules that i'd like to lazy load. I'm assuming that referencing those other modules in the landing page will cause the child modules to be downloaded at startup? Seems like I'll be right back where I started, loading all modules at startup. Is this true? Or maybe I'm missing something.

Looking for any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very interesting article about lazy loading components dynamically that's worth a read.

It obviously begs the question, "should you" but that's another question entirely!
If used well, it could be a good boost for your dashboard.

“Dynamically Loading Components with Angular CLI” https://blog.angularindepth.com/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28

Comment: Thanks Dylan. I think there might be some way I could make use of some of these ideas, i'll take a look